# Would a daughter be permitted to cohabitate with her father (after מתן תורה) in order to "save the world"?

Tags: giluy-arayos

Beraishis 19:31  --  בראשית יט:לא

ותאמר הבכירה אל־הצעירה אבינו זקן ואיש אין בארץ לבוא עלינו כדרך כל־הארץ

And the older one said to the younger, “Our father is old, and there is not a man on earth to consort with us in the way of all the world.

Rashi explains:
( ואיש אין בארץ סְבוּרוֹת הָיוּ, שֶׁכָּל הָעוֹלָם נֶחֱרַב כְּמוֹ בְּדוֹר הַמַּבּוּל: (בראשית רבה:

ואיש אין בארץ AND THERE IS NOT A MAN IN THE EARTH — They thought that the whole world had been destroyed as in the time of the generation of the Flood. (Beraishes Rabbah 51:8).

Theoretical question: If indeed the whole human race was destroyed, except for a father and his daughter, would they be permitted (after מתן תורה) to cohabitate in order to "save the world"?

Comment: @aBochur The daughters of Lot seemed to think it was a valid reason. I'm asking if they were theoretically justified, had it been after matan Torah.

Comment: This seems to be a theoretical question that **cannot happen**. As an example, Hashem promised Noach never to destroy *the entire world*. Similarly, hashem promised **never** to allow the Jewish people (as a people) to be destroyed. Indeed, there will always be descendants of all of the tribes. Since this cannot happen, the question would not be meaningful.

Comment: @sabbahillel Hashem promised Noach never to destroy the entire world BY FLOOD.

Comment: Is this the same as Esther with Achashveirosh and Yael with Sisera?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the "Noah's Sin" incident that it's not OK?

Comment: @Heshy Both Esther nad Yael were doing it to save people from death. we are dicussing doing it to make possible FUTURE humanity.

Answer (score 2):

Lot’s daughters are commended for their actions. There’s a fascinating sugya on the concept of an aveirah lishmah, a sin done for the sake of Heaven, discussed in Horayos 10b-11a. The following quotes are excerpts of it that are relevant to the OP, all from Sefaria.

> משל ללוט ושתי בנותיו הן שנתכוונו לשם מצוה צדיקים ילכו בם הוא שנתכוון לשם עבירה ופושעים יכשלו בם
>
> It is comparable to Lot and his two daughters. They, who intended to perform a mitzvah - “the righteous will walk in them;” he, who intended to sin - “the sinners will stumble in them.” [The Gemara proceeds to support its assertion that Lot intended to sin.]

---

> אמר רב נחמן בר יצחק גדולה עבירה לשמה ממצוה שלא לשמה שנאמר (שופטים ה, כד) תבורך מנשים יעל אשת חבר הקיני מנשים באהל תבורך מאן נינהו נשים באהל שרה רבקה רחל ולאה איני והאמר רב יהודה אמר רב לעולם יעסוק אדם בתורה ובמצות אפילו שלא לשמה שמתוך שלא לשמה בא לשמה אימא כמצוה שלא לשמה
>
> Says Rav Nachman bar Yitzchak: Great is a sin for the sake of Heaven, more so than a mitzvah not for its sake, as it says, “Blessed among women is Yael the wife of Chever HaKeini [who was intimate with Sisera, who was attacking Bnei Yisrael], to tire him out so she could kill him]; from women in the tent should she be blessed.” Who are the women in the tent? Sarah, Rivkah, Rachel, and Leah. Is that so? But Rav Yehudah said in the name of Rav: a person should always strive to do a mitzvah not for its sake, for through doing it not for its sake he will come to do it for its sake! Say that [an aveirah for its sake] is like a mitzvah not for its sake [but not better].

---

> א"ר חייא בר אבין א"ר יהושע בן קרחה לעולם יקדים אדם לדבר מצוה שבשכר לילה אחת שקדמה בכירה לצעירה זכתה וקדמתה ארבע דורות למלכות
>
> Says Rav Chiya bar Avin in the name of R’ Yehoshua Ben Karchah: A person should always be first to do a mitzvah, for in the merit of the one night which [Lot’s] older daughter preceded [his] younger daughter, she merited to precede four generations in kingship [as Rus, a descendant of Lot’s older daughter’s son Moav, had Oved, who had Yishai, who had David, who had Shlomo, who married Na’amah, a descendant of Lot’s younger daughter’s son].

---

I don’t see any halachic authorities that discuss this explicitly, post-Gemara.

Comment: I've heard (but don't know any details) that it's discussed in reference to Israeli spies in enemy countries (e.g. Eli Cohen, I don't think anyone would apply this to someone like Jonathan Pollard) who are also involved in הצלת כלל ישראל.